# C# .Any() used to check for an already existing element on a single dimensional list

Tags: c#

I'm seeing a lot of examples of .Any() used with custom defined lists. I have a list that only contains values and no keys. How can I make use of Any() with a single dimensional list.

Here's how far I have gotten already:

```
            List<string> thread_pause = null;
            if (thread_pause.Any(item => item == project_id)&&thread_pause!=null) 
            {
                show("Already In List!");
            }
            else
            {
                show(project_id);
                session.thread_pause.Insert(0, project_id);
            }
```

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Your usage of `Any` should work.  Are you `using System.Linq`?

Comment: @Jacob, well he is calling Any on a null ref so ...

Comment: You've just rewritten `Contains()`.

Comment: Do you want to know how to check if a list contains an item? Use the Contains method. Do you want to know how to use an extension method method? Include the namespace of its class. Do you want to know how to prevent the NullReferenceException? Swap the && arguments. What's your question?

Comment: The Null was causing it not to work. @guys So .Contains() works just like .Any(), and what makes any special; the ability to target keys?

Comment: `Contains` does **not** work "just" like `Any`. `Any` takes what amounts to `Func<T,bool>` which allows you to specify a match condition for each item in the list; it returns `true` if anything in the list, when passed to the match condition, returns true. `Contains` just takes an instance of `T` and returns `true` if it matches anything in the list.

Comment: @Shibumi But his usage of `Any` is just like `thread_pause.Contains(project_id)`

Comment: @Magnus Granted :). Generically speaking, though, the phrase _Contains works just like Any._ is false.

Comment: `Any` can be considered a generalisation of `Contains` that is much more flexible, and `Contains` a specialisation of `Any` that is cheaper and more concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
List<string> thread_pause = null;
if (thread_pause.Any(...))
```

means you start by calling `null.Any()`. It won't work well.

Better change the first line to

```
 List<string> thread_pause = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no point doing `foo.DoStuff() && foo != null`, because it will try them in left-to-right order. You should have:

```
if(thread_pause != null && thread_pause.Contains(project_id))
```

There's no need for `Any` because lists already have a more efficient method that finds an exact match.

For the sake of argument, if you had a more complicated thing to search for (say a case-insensitive search, then:

```
thread_pause != null && thread_pause.Any(item => item.ToUpperInvariant() == project_id.ToUpperInvariant())
```

Comment: Is it really "more efficient" ?

Comment: Yes, since it does a straight call to Equals rather than use a execute a lambda. It's not a major factor here and if it weren't also more concise and longer-known I wouldn't choose it most of the time.